# Delphi - form maximized event

Tags: delphi

I want to call a function after a form has been maxmized or restored.
I know I can something like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.WMSysCommand;
begin
   if (Msg.CmdType = SC_MAXIMIZE) OR (Msg.CmdType = SC_RESTORE) then
   begin
     Showmessage(IntToStr(frmMain.Height));
   end;
   DefaultHandler(Msg) ;
end;
```

But the problem is: this event is fired before the form is actually resized - so when the form is maximized, I get the height of the form BEFORE it was maxmized (but I want the width of the form after it has been maximized).

How to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the following link maybe will help you:

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=809465&page=176

declare this into interface section of this unit

```
Procedure sizeMove (var msg: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
```

and implementation of this procedure:

```
Procedure TfrmMain.sizeMove (var msg: TWMSize);
begin 
 inherited; 
 if (msg.SizeType = SIZE_MAXIMIZED) OR (msg.SizeType = SIZE_RESTORED)then   
  resizeQlikViewReports(); 
end;
```

Comment: if you post links to articles, would you please include some info about the article behind the link, perhaps at least the article's title?

Comment: @Marjan : I was in hurry, that was the reason to put only the links...next time i will be more explicit :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnResize either and check WindowState. It's easier way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).